# What are the options for changing the behavior of a Django/python module?

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I want to change the behavior of a class method without re-implementing large portions of the module. What are my options for doing this?

I’m using the wagtail_blog module in a current project. Separate models are created for Blog and BlogIndexPage. The BlogIndexPage returns a list of all related Blog pages. I want to introduce a method to limit the returned pages by Category, and this is where my question comes in-—what are the best options for doing this?

- I could create a new app (MyBlog), inherit from the original classes,
  and override get_context(). The problem with this is that I would
  also need to re-implement other parts of the code as object names
  would now be different.
- I could fork the original repo, add in my changes, and use this in
  my project. Again, lots of work for a small change.
- Something more elegant that you clever people can suggest.

How do others normally handle this situation?

For completeness, here’s the code I’m working on:

```
def get_blog_context(context):
    """ Get context data useful on all blog related pages """
    context['authors'] = get_user_model().objects.filter(
        owned_pages__live=True,
        owned_pages__content_type__model='blogpage'
    ).annotate(Count('owned_pages')).order_by('-owned_pages__count')
    context['all_categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.all()
    context['root_categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.filter(
        parent=None,
    ).prefetch_related(
        'children',
    ).annotate(
        blog_count=Count('blogpage'),
    )
    return context


class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    @property
    def blogs(self):
        # Get list of blog pages that are descendants of this page
        blogs = BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live()
        blogs = blogs.order_by(
            '-date'
        ).select_related('owner').prefetch_related(
            'tagged_items__tag',
            'categories',
            'categories__category',
        )
        return blogs

    def get_context(self, request, tag=None, category=None, author=None, *args,
                    **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
        blogs = self.blogs

        if tag is None:
            tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        if tag:
            blogs = blogs.filter(tags__slug=tag)
        if category is None:  # Not coming from category_view in views.py
            if request.GET.get('category'):
                category = get_object_or_404(
                    BlogCategory, slug=request.GET.get('category'))
        if category:
            if not request.GET.get('category'):
                category = get_object_or_404(BlogCategory, slug=category)
            blogs = blogs.filter(categories__category__name=category)
        if author:
            if isinstance(author, str) and not author.isdigit():
                blogs = blogs.filter(author__username=author)
            else:
                blogs = blogs.filter(author_id=author)

        # Pagination
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        page_size = 10
        if hasattr(settings, 'BLOG_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE'):
            page_size = settings.BLOG_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE

        if page_size is not None:
            paginator = Paginator(blogs, page_size)  # Show 10 blogs per page
            try:
                blogs = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                blogs = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                blogs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['blogs'] = blogs
        context['category'] = category
        context['tag'] = tag
        context['author'] = author
        context['COMMENTS_APP'] = COMMENTS_APP
        context = get_blog_context(context)

        return context

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Blog index')
    subpage_types = ['blog.BlogPage']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `wagtail` CMS, but I guess you can do something like:

```
class MyBlogIndexPage(BlogIndexPage):
    def get_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyBlogIndexPage, self).get_context(*args, **kwargs)
        #do context changes
        return context
```

And now override the the `view/views` which use the old `BlogIndexPage`. *(Again I'm not familiar with the wagtail system, just saw [how](https://github.com/thelabnyc/wagtail_blog/blob/f84b2f3edd1110037b9a9b74136ff199b5d84329/blog/views.py#L8) the `BlogIndexPage` is being used.)*

```
def my_tag_view(request, tag):
    index = MyBlogIndexPage.objects.first()
    return index.serve(request, tag=tag)
```

Finally override the `url` to use your `view`.

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/', views.my_tag_view, name="tag"),
```

Comment: Thanks Todor. The odd thing with Wagtail is that you don't use views with the api. You just define a model and Wagtail handles the rest in the background.  You answer lines up with my first option in that you really need to create an new app with new models and templates, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm not sure a whole new app is necessary, look at my answers, that are 10 lines of code, its not a new app, you are just extending an existing app.